# When we bind a texture created in unity to opengl the internal format is modified

Tags: unity-game-engine, opengl, textures

I want to manipulate a texture that has been created in Unity directly with OpenGL.

I create the texture in unity with these parameters :

```cs
_renderTexture = new RenderTexture(_sizeTexture, _sizeTexture, 0
    , RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32, RenderTextureReadWrite.Linear)
{
    useMipMap = false,
    autoGenerateMips = false,
    anisoLevel = 6,
    filterMode = FilterMode.Trilinear,
    wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp,
    enableRandomWrite = true
};
```

Then I send the texture pointer to a native rendering plugin with `GetNativeTexturePtr()` method. In the native rendering plugin I bind the texture with `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gltex);` where `gltex` is the pointer of my texture in Unity.

Finally, I check the internal format of my texture with :

```c
GLint format;
glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_INTERNAL_FORMAT, &format);
```

I have `format = GL_RGBA8` even though I defined the texture in Unity with the format `RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32`. You can reproduce this by using the [native rendering plugin example of Unity](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/NativeRenderingPlugin) and just replacing the function `RenderAPI_OpenGLCoreES::EndModifyTexture` of the file `RenderAPI_OpenGLCoreES.cpp` by :

```cpp
void RenderAPI_OpenGLCoreES::EndModifyTexture(void* textureHandle, int textureWidth, int textureHeight, int rowPitch, void* dataPtr)
{
    GLuint gltex = (GLuint)(size_t)(textureHandle);
    // Update texture data, and free the memory buffer
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gltex);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB32F, textureWidth, textureHeight, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, textureWidth, textureHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, dataPtr);


    GLint format;
    glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_INTERNAL_FORMAT,
        &format);

    delete[](unsigned char*)dataPtr;
}
```

Why did the internal format change after binding the texture to OpenGL? And is it possible to "impose" `GL_RGBA32F` format to my OpenGL texture?

I tried to use `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, textureWidth, textureHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);` after my binding but I get the following error: `Error : OpenGL error 0x0502 (GL_INVALID_OPERATION)`.

Sorry if the question is simple I am new on OpenGL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just misread the documentation, moreover unity and open have not the same naming convention... I thought `RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32` was a texture with 32 bit per channel, but it's a **total of 32 bit** and therefore 8 bit per channel which corresponds to `GL_RGBA8`.
There is a summary table for unity format here : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ComputeShader.html.